# Not able to reload page by using Refresh Indicator in my flutter project

Tags: flutter, dart, refresh, future, page-refresh

[image: All these nodes data are updated everytime after fetch method is called]> i am making a app that uses http get request to fetch data from server

> i want to be able to refresh page by using refresh indicator widget
>   whose refresh method calls my get request every time

```
     Future<void> fetch() async {
        const url = "https:*********.firebaseio.com/nodes.json";
        final response = await http.get(url);
        final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
        List<Node> value = [];
        extractedData.forEach((key, v) {
          value.add(
              Node(cpu: v['cpu'], memory: v['memory'], isLeader: v['_isleader']));
          setState(() {
            _nodes = value;
          });
        });
      }

  void initState() {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });
    fetch().then((_) {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }


    body: RefreshIndicator(
            onRefresh: fetch,
            child: _isLoading == true
                ? Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  )
                : Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        child: Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                          child: Image.network(
                            "https://rendr.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/Website-Maintenance-Animation.gif",
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
```

Comment: Please post your refresh method code

Comment: sorry the name refresh was just a typo while posting question

Comment: i am calling fetch from there

Comment: just look at my init state code which which is loading this page using fetch but i am not able to refresh after that so to update values i have to reopen my app each time 

Answer (score 0):

Can u show the full code? I think you need to replace `onRefresh: refresh,` to `onRefresh: fetch(),`

Comment: sorry it was just a typo i am using fetch in my real code but then also it's not working

Comment: it is fetching only when app restarts i mean to say only when init state runs